# Placing an element above an existing element JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm using the drag and drop functionality with JavaScript.

I have cards inserted into a panel and I want them to, when dragged, insert into the new panel depending on the urgency of the item.

`retrieveInd()` gets the urgency of an item, using a class connected to it, with a number so it is easier to compare: 0 to 3.

```js
function retrieveInd(u) {
    var us = ['low','medium','high','critical'];
    for(x = 0; x < us.length; x++){
        if(us[x] === u){
            return x;
        } 
    }
}
  
function drop(ev, el) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    let u = ((document.getElementById(data).getElementsByClassName('urgency'))[0].classList[1]);


    var els = el.querySelectorAll('.panel-item');
    
    els.forEach((elx) => {
        var cel = retrieveInd(elx.getElementsByClassName('urgency')[0].classList[1]);
        console.log(retrieveInd(u), cel)
        if(u > cel){
            el.insertBefore(elx, document.getElementById(data))
        }
    })

}
```

An example of a panel-item

```html
<div class="panel-item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="panel-item-1">
                        
                        <div class="panel-item-title">

                            panel title
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-item-urgency">

                            <div class="urgency critical"></div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
```

My code does not work, infact it doesn't actually let the drop functionality work.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Uh, small note, your whole `retrieveInd` method is just a self implemented version of the `indexOf` method for arrays.  `['low', 'medium', 'high', 'critical'].indexOf(u)` would do effectively the same thing.

Comment: @Taplar thanks completely forgot about that!